How to change shape of multi head self-attention output to a shape that can be fed to convolution layer?
I encountered an error like this:
The output of MHSA (multi-head self-attention) is as follows:
torch.Size([20, 197, 768])


20 for batch size
197 for sequence length (previously 196, after adding the class token it became 197)
768 for embedding dimension

I want to reshape it to fit the format below in order to feed it to a convolutional layer:
torch.Size([batch_size, channel, width, height])

I've attempted to achieve this by adding a new dimension using the following approach:
torch.unsqueeze(1)
torch.transpose(1, 3)

This successfully allows feeding to the convolutional layer. However, I'm unsure if this approach is correct, so please correct me if it's not.
Currently, I'm trying a different approach:
new_size = int(math.sqrt(sequence_length))
torch.transpose(1, 2).view(batch_size, embed_dim, new_size, new_size)

This resulted in an error stating that the shape is invalid for an input of size (some_number). This is because the sequence length (197) doesn't square perfectly, yielding a decimal number, and the view function expects an integer input, the square operation yields 16 after converting to an integer, but batch_size * 768 * 16 * 16 does not equal batch_size * 197 * 768, leading to the error
Is my analysis correct? And how can I resolve this issue? and is there any better approach?

There is no "correct" option here as it is meaningless to convolve over the embedding dimension (we cannot assume any local structures between adjacent dimensions). So any method that doesn't crash will be "correct" in the same way.

Ah I don't about that, thank you for your correction, can you tell me exactly should I apply the convolution? My goal is to replace the MLP in the feed forward network with convolution

To apply convolutions to sequence data, you want to use a 1D convolution (ie Conv1D instead of Conv2D).
The 1D conv operation expects an input of shape (batch_size, channels, d) which matches your tensor of shape (batch_size, sequence_length, d).
HOWEVER convolutions (both 1D and 2D) expect a fixed size input. This is problematic because sequence data is typically variable length in the sequence_length dimension.
You can get around this by defining a maximum sequence length and padding all inputs to that sequence length. You could do something like this:
def pad_tensor(x, max_size):
    batch_size, sequence_length, d = x.size()
    
    pad_size = max_size - sequence_length
    
    if pad_size <= 0:
        return x
    
    padding = (0, 0,
               0, pad_size,
               0, 0)
    
    padded_x = torch.nn.functional.pad(x, padding, mode='constant', value=0)
    
    return padded_x

class PaddedConv1D(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, max_size, **conv_kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.conv = nn.Conv1d(in_channels=max_size, out_channels=max_size, **conv_kwargs)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        sequence_length = x.shape[1]
        x = pad_tensor(x, self.max_size)
        x = self.conv(x)
        return x[:, :sequence_length]

However but this is computationally wasteful. You're better off sticking with an operation that works with variable sequence lengths.
That said, it seems like your intent is to replace the feed forward layer of the transformer. In this case using a convolution doesn't really make sense. The convolution operates across the sequence length, while the FF layer operates on each input time step individually. You could (technically speaking) do a 1D conv along the embedding dimension but this doesn't really make sense. Convolving along the embedding dimension actually uses more flops to produce the same output size compared to a FF layer. You can benchmark the following code to verify.
x = torch.randn(8, 17, 64)

ff = nn.Linear(64, 64)

conv = nn.Conv1d(64, 64, 3, padding=1)

y1 = ff(x)
y2 = conv(x.permute(0, 2, 1)).permute(0,2,1)


Thank you for answering, I am starting to understand a little, but some things are still confusing. Previously, I saw the code in this link https://github.com/apple/ml-fastvit/blob/main/models/fastvit.py, where Apple places a 2D convolution as a replacement for the feed forward network after multi head self attention. Can you please explain why this is done if the convolution does not have an impact and is heavier, or is there something different?

First re-read my post. Conv is heavier in the specific case where you are convolving over the embedding dimension of your specific input shape. The paper you linked operates on images of shape (bs, ch, h, w) with a fixed number of input channels. Fixed ch size avoids the variable length issue that sequence data has. It performs standard convs over the ch dimension, which is much lighter compared to a dense feed forward.

I am still confused about the specific input part, has my code here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VQwo_8OsI9dqg3kxuhP9GdMSF3RwlB26 already implemented specific input?
